# Error valor devuelto en pipe

Tags: c

Me piden hacer una función que primero haga un ls del directorio actual y lo almaceno en un archivo (tmp) y luego, que lea de ese archivo, haga un grep -c y devuelva el valor en el return. No consigo que me devuelva correctamente el valor correcto en int, sí como char.

```
int do_nfiles (char *pattern)
    {
      t_string s;
      int fd[2],fd2[2];
      char buf[100];
      int val = 10;

      delay ();
      pipe(fd);
      int pid = fork();

       /*Proceso hijo*/
      if(pid == 0){

          fd[0] = open("tmp", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0666);
          dup2(fd[0],STDOUT_FILENO);
          close(fd[0]);
          execlp("ls","ls", NULL);
      }
      else{
          pipe(fd2);
          pid = fork();

          if(pid == 0){
            fd2[0] = open("tmp", O_RDONLY);
            dup2(fd2[0],STDIN_FILENO);
            dup2(fd2[1],STDOUT_FILENO);
            close(fd2[0]);
            execlp("grep","grep","-c",pattern, NULL);
          }

          read(fd2[0], &val, sizeof(val));
          sprintf (s, "[%d] num %d\n", getpid (), val);

        return (val);
      }

      return 0;
    }
```

Si modifico la función y pongo esto:

```
read(fd2[0],buf,3);
```

Me devuelve el valor correcto en char, no en int.

Comment: Tu pregunta no concierne el lenguaje C#.

Answer (score 0):

Sin ejecutarlo, veo que usas la salida de un *comando* como entrada de datos. Todos los comandos *shell* que uses muestran los datos como cadenas de texto, no como tipos básicos del lenguaje. Es lógico, puesto que son comandos pensados para *ser usados por humanos*.

Tienes que convertir el *fd* en un *stream* con `fdopen( )`, y, a partir de ahí, usar las funciones de formateo de entradas `scanf( )`.

Comment: Gracias!!!! Ha funcionado! =)